# What's the cleanest way to match "profile view" or "view_profile" but not "profile.profile" or "view(view)"?

Tags: regex

I'm basically looking for a regex that will match these:

```
ProfileView
profile_views
views of candidate profile
viewed_profile
```

But not these:

```
profile(profile)
view = candidate.view
```

In other words, I want `a.+b` or `b.+a` but not `a.+a` or `b.+b`.

I thought this would require capture groups in some way, but I'm not quite sure how. `(a|b).+(^\1)`... something like that if you catch my meaning.

Comment: what do you mean by a and b?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use the alternation operator `|`.

```
(?i)^(?:profile.*views?|views?.*profile)$
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/uS5qR5/1)

`s?` matches an optional `s`. `(?i)` case-insensitive modifier which helps to do a case-insensitive match.

Comment: Thanks, I was hoping the answer would be less... "dumb", but this works. Thanks!

Comment: Answers are like questions, the dumb ones are the ones that don't get formulated/answered.